# Unexpected arithmetic result with zero padded numbers

Tags: shell, arithmetic-expressions

I have a problem in my script wherein I'm reading a file and each line has data which is a representation of an amount. The said field always has a length of 12 and it's always a whole number. So let's say I have an amount of 25,000, the data will look like this `000000025000`.

Apparently, I have to get the total amount of these lines but the zero prefixes are disrupting the computation. If I add the above mentioned number to a zero value like this:

```
echo $(( 0 + 000000025000 ))
```

Instead of getting `25000`, I get `10752` instead. I was thinking of looping through `000000025000` and when I finally get a non-zero value, I'm going to substring the number from that index onwards. However, I'm hoping that there must be a more elegant solution for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The number `000000025000` is an octal number as it starts with `0`.

If you use bash as your shell, you can use the prefix `10#` to force the base number to decimal:

```
echo $(( 10#000000025000 ))
```

From the bash man pages:

> Constants  with a leading 0 are interpreted as octal numbers.  A leading 0x or 0X denotes hexadecimal.  Otherwise, numbers take the form [base#]n, where the optional base is a decimal number between 2 and 64 representing the arithmetic base, and n is a number in that base.

Comment: I can't believe how that was easily solved. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Using Perl

```
$ echo "000000025000" | perl -ne ' { printf("%d\n",scalar($_)) } '
25000
```