# In the bash conditional statement, why 216 is greater than 0330?

Tags: bash

In the Bash 215 is not greater then 0330.

```
$ N=215 ; if [[ $N -ge 0330 ]]; then echo ok ; else echo no; fi
no
```

But, 216 is not greater than 0330. I think it's so weird. Why is this happening?

```
$ N=216 ; if [[ $N -ge 0330 ]]; then echo ok ; else echo no; fi
ok
$ N=217 ; if [[ $N -ge 0330 ]]; then echo ok ; else echo no; fi
ok
```

I expect that '329 -ge 0330' is no and '330 -ge 0330' is ok.

Comment: `0330` (in radix 8) is 3×8×8 + 3×8 = `216` (in radix 10)

Comment: Bash treats numbers that start with "0" as octal, rather than decimal. See ["Unexpected arithmetic result with zero padded numbers"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53205175/unexpected-arithmetic-result-with-zero-padded-numbers).

Comment: Also see [Value too great for base (error token is "08")](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24777597/4154375).

Comment: `0330 == 216` that's why your `-ge` (greater than or equal to) tests true from `216` on...

Answer (score 2):

Pick up the *radix*:

with zero leading, bash 'think' he have to handle *octal* notation.

```bash
$ N=216 ; if ((N < 10#0330)); then echo ok ; else echo no; fi 
#                  ^^^
#                base 10
ok
```

http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ArithmeticExpression

Answer (score 1):

`0330` is interpreted as an octal number because it starts with a leading zero. In octal notation, the decimal value `330` is represented as `516`, which is greater than `215`.